# Debugging a runnable groovy class via IntelliJ

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea

I'm successfully debugging this script in Intellij:

```
println "a";
println "b";
```

But, when trying to debug the following script, my breakpoints aren't hit

```
public class Main implements Runnable{
  public Main(String[] args) {
    println("A"); // breakpoint
    println "B";

  }

  void run() {
    println "C"; // breakpoint
    println "D";
  }
}
```

Note that the script does run successfully, just without stopping at breakpoints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI this bug is fixed in IDEA 11.1

Answer (score 1):

This is correct main method signature:

```
static void main(String[] args) {...}
```

I believe that you should not expect for run() method to execute as you don't actually run it in a separate thread or invoke directly..

Comment: Groovy will run a Runnable class by itself as the entry point to the script.

Comment: @ripper234 You're right, IntelliJ does execute run(), I didn't know that. Btw my IntelliJ does stop on both breakpoints when debugging..

Comment: well, next time I'll debug a groovy script I'll give it a try, maybe since then it's been fixed.